# Are PIE files given virtual memory address during linking?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, position-independent-code

I have compiled a simple `hello world` c code with `gcc -fpie test.c`,
and now looking at the binary using `objdump`:

```
Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:
__text:
100000f40:  55  pushq   %rbp
100000f41:  48 89 e5    movq    %rsp, %rbp
100000f44:  48 83 ec 10     subq    $16, %rsp
100000f48:  89 7d fc    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
100000f4b:  8b 75 fc    movl    -4(%rbp), %esi
100000f4e:  48 8d 3d 5d 00 00 00    leaq    93(%rip), %rdi
100000f55:  b0 00   movb    $0, %al

...
```

We can clearly see memory addresses are still calculated by the linker on the left. Aren't `pie` files supposed to have no memory addresses associated to them statically?

My second question is, how are `pic` files (like shared libraries) loaded in memory? do they have their own virtual address space? if so why do they need to be position independent? or are they loaded into a processes address space?

Answer (score 1):

Those are not addresses. What you should be looking at are the PC-relative offsets:

```
leaq    93(%rip), %rdi
```

These signify that the code is PIC/PIE.

Shared libraries are mapped into every running process that uses them.
These libraries, however, need to be relocated (to fit the address space constraints of the program), and so are compiled with PIC (position-independent code, a.k.a. usually with PC-relative offsets).

Comment: Thank you, so there are address spaces outside of virtual memory where every process has access to? or its still virtual memory but shared between all processec?

Comment: @Josh: Whether it's PIE has nothing to do with whether the memory is shared (read-only mappings of program text/data are always shared).

Comment: They're not "offsets in the file", though they may happen to be equal to offsets in the file. They're virtual (not runtime-virtual, rather ELF load mapping virtual) addresses in the `PT_LOAD` segments of the ELF file. For PIC/PIE these generally start at 0, but could start at something arbitrary and nonzero. At runtime they're shifted by a constant offset equal to whatever address the PIC/PIE shared library or program gets loaded at minus the base virtual address in the ELF load map. Address references in initialized global data have to be adjusted by this offset; ...

Comment: ...program text does not need to be adjusted because it does not contain any absolute addresses, only relative ones, which don't change regardless of where it's loaded.

Comment: @Josh Sort of.. The shared library is mapped into every process that uses it.